# Emptiness of emptiness

Tags: personal-practice, sunyata

Is the following idea of mine a good way to practice the emptiness of emptiness in my everyday non meditational etc., life?

Does anyone suggest something like this, in any Buddhist tradition?

> realizing your past happiness is worthless and that no way of thinking about it has any worth, and being happy about that

Comment: If you're new to meditation find a teacher. It will save you a lot of time in the beginning.

Comment: no i'm not, really. also i DID ask about outside meditation :)

Comment: I assume your reply means "I'm not new"? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: More on topic however, you seem to be asking two questions. It's implied that the second is related to the first, but far from obvious how it is related. If you read this material somewhere, can you source it for clarification, or somehow restate the question?

Comment: i r can't see two unrelated questions there !

i've seen meditation teachers i number of times... :)

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting to begin to understand things about yourself, your actions, your motivations and about what is worthwhile, wholesome, beneficial, and what is not. Some types of meditation can help greatly with these understandings and some would say there should be no "non meditational" part of your day. Every waking moment has the potential to be a mindful moment of being aware of what you are doing and why you are doing it and this can facilitate further understanding of yourself, your actions, your motivations.

I'm not sure that one "practices" emptiness. One hopes to understand emptiness and understanding could come from mindfulness both inside and outside of formal meditation.

But as a disclaimer, in the tradition I practice, the concept is anatta, not emptiness, so there might be subtle differences with emptiness of which I am not familiar.